# Stop receiving touch events when the mouse is moved

Tags: windows, windows-7, touch, mouse, hook

I am attempting to hook an application and drive the mouse via WM_TOUCH events. In order to do this I have hooked WH_GETMESSAGE and am able to successfully receive WM_TOUCH events. After receiving the touch events, I then make calls to sendInput() to produce the desired mouse functionality; however, the moment I make the mouse calls via sendInput() I stop receiving WM_TOUCH events.

I thought this was due to the placement of my sendinput() calls; however, after taking out all calls to sendInput(), I was able to confirm using Spy++ that any input from the mouse --that is, me physically moving the mouse, resulted in the interruption of  the WM_TOUCH events.

Lastly, I created a WPF application which contained simple callbacks on the for all touch events. I can put my finger on the form and receive events; however, the moment I move the physical mouse, the WPF program receives a TouchUp event followed by TouchLeave event, even though my finger is still moving on the touch screen.

I was hoping that someone would be able to shed some light on why this is happening and if it is possible for me to produce my desired functionality.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This doesn't sound like anymore more than Windows trying to deal with multiple sources of pointer input.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would not explain why Windows 7 itself is able to inject mouse input in response to touch input, i.e., mouse emulation of drag drop etc..., Spy++ confirms Windows is indeed injecting mouse commands. Perhaps I should note that it is not simply an interruption of WM_TOUCH events, but a complete cessation of touch events until I lift my finger from the touch device and put it down again.